# Select $value from selected table rows for form post - only the last table data is posted

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to map table data and post the result to my database, but only the bottom / last table rows data gets posted. How can i select which rows get posted using the checkbox and post the data for all selected rows?

I simply want to post the attributeid (image column2 / attributeid) and drop down value from (image column 4 / csvoption)

[image]

```
//DB connection
require("../config/db/connection.php");
//Session UserID
$userid = htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['userid']);
    
// Get Attribute List
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, name FROM attributes WHERE userid = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $userid);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
if($result != NULL){
    while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
        $option =$row['name'];
        $id =$row['id'];
        echo '<table width="100%">';            
        echo '<tr>';                
        //echo '<td width="25%">';        
        echo '<td width="25%"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_selected" id="checkbox_selected" value="1"> </checkbox></td>';                      
        //here we creating normal cells <td></td>       
        echo'<input type="hidden" name="attributeid" value="' . $id . '">';
        echo '<td id="attributeid" name="attributeid" width="25%">' . $id . '</td>';
        echo '<td width="25%">' . $option . '</td>';
        //Select Drop Down List of CSV Columns
        echo'<td width="25%"><select name="csvoption" required>';                           
        //Call function to map CSV drop 
        mapcsv();
        echo'</select></td>';   
                        
        echo '</tr>';   
        echo '</table>';                 
    } 
             
}
}
```

my html form post:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $response = ftpmap(
        htmlspecialchars ($_POST['header_row']),
        htmlspecialchars ($_POST['csvoption']),
        htmlspecialchars ($_POST['attributeid']));
};
```

Only row 9 data gets posted:
attributeid = 9
csvoption = 3 (dependant on selected drop down selected option)

Comment: You shouldn't start a new table for each row. Put `<table>` and `</table>` outside the loop.

Comment: You have an unmatched `}` at the end of the first code block.

Comment: If you want to submit all the rows in the table, give them array-style names: `name="attributeid[]"`. Then `$_POST['attributeid']` will be an array of all the values.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the help yet again! I've amended the <table> outside the loop. I cant see the unmatched } though and its compiling without flagging it!?

Comment: @Barmar i've also amended the names to array style names and all values appear to post for all rows (i need to work on an amended implode insert statement now as its an array)

How would you advise to post just the selected rows? Is this possible by PHP or would i need to look at using Java?

Comment: I'm guessing there's another `if` before the code you posted, and the `}` at the end is matching that.

Comment: I did it once with JavaScript. I wrote a submit event listener that loops through the table, deleting the rows that aren't selected. Then the rest were submitted.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for advice, appreciated!